# add alias to my virtual host

Tags: php, symfony, virtualhost, apache2.4

I've deployed my project symfony2 on a personal server and everything works fine.

Now I want to publish this project for some friends so that they can see it. I thought that the best would be to access my project from outside through /.
Quick google research made think that it's possible with Alias statement.

```
ServerName blabla
ServerAlias blablab
ServerAdmin blablab@blabla
DocumentRoot /path/to/my/project/web     

Alias /myproject "/path/to/my/project/web"
<Directory /path/to/my/project/web>
   DirectoryIndex app.php
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I try to access `<server_IP_ADDRESS>/<project_name>` I got `Not found` error

Why this error? How do I fix this ?

**UPDATE1**

I have many projects on one server, and I'd like to be able to access them anywhere I'm. The best option from my point of view is to use Aliases:

1. project1: `http://<my_server_ip_address>/project1`
2. project2: `http://<my_server_ip_address>/project2`
3. project3: `http://<my_server_ip_address>/project3`
   ....

Comment: Your alias creates the path `/myproject`.  According to your `DocumentRoot`, the path `/` does point to the same directory as the alias `/myproject`. What other settings are in the `<Directory>` directive? Did you restart Apache after making your canges?  Does this server have other virtualhosts?

Comment: I've updated my post, and yes my server does have many virtual hosts

Comment: You can access the virtual server from the browser by entering the `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`. If you're getting not found then you've set a wrong path. Also I don't get what the alias before the directory directive is for.

Comment: @php_nub_qq thx for your answer, I've updated my post please have a look.

Comment: Oh no, that's not how it works. I'll try to explain what I know, but have in mind that I'm not a server guru and the information I will give may not be 100% correct as in there may be better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a virtual server will map a server to a host name / alias. In your case you are accessing the same host name (the server ip) but different URIs. In your case these URIs may not exist, thus you need to redirect/rewrite them. I think you would be looking for rewrite so you can just go ahead and put rewrite rules in the virtual host definition as in `.htaccess` just make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled.

```
ServerName <server ip>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /project1 /Path/to/project/1 [L]
RewriteRule /project2 /Path/to/project/2 [L]
RewriteRule /project3 /Path/to/project/3 [L]
```